# Crashing when navigating back from fragment with compose view

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-architecture-navigation

TimelineFragment

```
class TimelineFragment : Fragment() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        
        val axis = MaterialSharedAxis.Z

        val forward = MaterialSharedAxis(axis, true)
        val backward = MaterialSharedAxis(axis, false)

        enterTransition = forward
        exitTransition = forward
        reenterTransition = backward
        returnTransition = backward
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ) = ComposeView(requireActivity()).apply { 
        setContent { 
            Text(text = "Testing")
        }
    }
}
```

when clicking back button from this fragment the app is crashing and printing this stacktrace

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.farmersbyte.agripro, PID: 8524
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Cannot add views to ComposeView; only Compose content is supported
    at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AbstractComposeView.checkAddView(ComposeView.android.kt:202)
    at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AbstractComposeView.addView(ComposeView.android.kt:346)
    at androidx.transition.TransitionUtils.createViewBitmap(TransitionUtils.java:138)
    at androidx.transition.TransitionUtils.copyViewImage(TransitionUtils.java:64)
    at androidx.transition.Visibility.onDisappear(Visibility.java:404)
    at androidx.transition.Visibility.createAnimator(Visibility.java:257)
    at androidx.transition.Transition.createAnimators(Transition.java:744)
    at androidx.transition.TransitionSet.createAnimators(TransitionSet.java:480)
    at androidx.transition.TransitionSet.createAnimators(TransitionSet.java:480)
    at androidx.transition.Transition.playTransition(Transition.java:1808)
    at androidx.transition.TransitionManager$MultiListener.onPreDraw(TransitionManager.java:300)
    at android.view.ViewTreeObserver.dispatchOnPreDraw(ViewTreeObserver.java:1088)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2745)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1721)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:7598)
    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:966)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:790)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:725)
    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:951)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
```

Using jetpack navigation component for fragment navigations. crash is only happening when back press with `MaterialSharedAxis` transition set for fragment.

Edit: No issues in compose `1.0.1` but getting crashes in version `1.1.0` and above.

Comment: Did you find any solution for this?

Comment: Nope, Temporarily removed MaterialSharedAxis transition.

Comment: Have you opened a bug report on Google Issue tracker? If so, can you send a link? I'll upvote and follow

Comment: Link to issue https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/236561967

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solved by setting `isTransitionGroup` to `true` for `ComposeView`.

Sample Code:

```
class TestFragment : Fragment() {

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ) = ComposeView(context).apply {
        isTransitionGroup = true 
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. If you have Fragment A and B. Fragment A has exitTransition setup, and when navigating from A to B, it crashes with the error. So my fix is to remove exitTransition. Think it is a bug in new compose library. I only saw this issue when I upgraded to the lastest versions: compose.* 1.1.1 with compose.compiler 1.2.

Comment: Posted working answer